# Promoted Results Best Practices

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search, promoted-results

My current client has a dynamically-generated HR content system that is very difficult to index in Enterprise Search. They have opted instead to create huge and convoluted lists of promoted results to point people to a handful of pages within their system (6 pages total, up to 4 of which can fire for any given term). This creates some very unpleasant situations in which general terms like "R&D Project Form" can fire 4 HR query rules because of the word "form".

I wish it were as easy as cleaning up the query rules to filter out common words like that, but since this is the only way their system gets visibility they are extremely resistant to the idea of being cut back. Are there any best practices related to usage of promoted results that I can use to convince them it's just not a viable strategy? Or that perhaps show I'm the one who is wrong so I can stop being annoyed by it and drop the subject?

Currently I'm thinking of restrictions like "No more than two results should fire for any given term" as a starting point, but I'm just not sure if that's a valid way to go about it or if that's just my annoyance talking. I do have anecdotal evidence from a handful of users that they too are annoyed by the amount of promoted results that pop up for unrelated terms, but I don't know how to objectively prove it's a bad idea to have them.

Comment: if people aren't finding what they need, it is a problem plain and simple

Comment: Believe me, I'm aware, and trying to prove to them that nobody is even using the promoted results anyways but the tail trimming metric in SP is preventing me from absolutely proving it (all these query rules are showing 0 clicks per month, though it could theoretically be up to 3 per day without that metric actually incrementing). The problem is they think *this* is the solution to their problem, but I need to get them to go a different direction.